# Delphi Launching external application "No activity found"

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent

I want to start/run/launch an application that I have written in Embarcadero XE7 (Delphi) from another application I am writing just now.

```
function LaunchActivity(const Intent: JIntent): Boolean; overload;
begin
  SharedActivity.getPackageManager.resolveActivity(Intent, 0);
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('com.embarcadero.Server.MAIN'));
  Intent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.embarcadero.Server'));
  LaunchActivity(Intent) 
end;
```

**Some content of the Manifest file of the application to be launched:**

```xml
<intent-filter>  
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I think the manifest file is correct, showing I can call the application. However, when I run the program it says that

> No activity found to handle Intent {act=com.embarcadero.Server.MAIN
>   pkg=com.embaracdero.Server}

I tried with `android.intent.action.MAIN` with the some result.

What is missing?

Comment: See [Sending Android Intents from Delphi (Part 1)](http://www.danieleteti.it/2013/09/26/sending-android-intents-from-delphi-part-1/) and [Sending Android Intents from Delphi (Part 2)](http://www.danieleteti.it/2014/01/13/sending-android-intents-from-delphi-part-2/).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for launching an external application WITHOUT sending any text file or similar. In all the examples I found you send a file or something like "http://google.com".

**IMPORTANT  --> This is for just launching the external application. No information is passed / sent to the application.**

Two ways.

1.- The application to be launched has no visible icon on the phone, but you can start it from another application.

```
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

2.- The application has a visible icon in the phone to launch / start it manually. And you can launch it from another application.

```
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 
         <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The delphi code to launch the application in both cases is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.embarcadero.Server2'));
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Where com.embarcadero.Server2 is the name of the package of the application to be launched.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
Intent := TJIntent.Create;
Intent := SharedActivity.getPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(StringToJString(s));
SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```